# MY scrapy spider just show me the first two pages of site

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

here is my code. i'm beginner in Python and my scrapy pagination just repeat first tow pages.

```
import scrapy


class HotelabbasiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'HotelAbbasi'
    allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g295423-d320767-Reviews-or5']
    page_number=5
    def content_parse(self,response):
        for part in response.css('div.hotels-community-tab-common-Card__section--4r93H'):
            item={
                'reviewer':part.css('a.social-member-event-MemberEventOnObjectBlock__member--35-jC::text').extract_first(),
                'Date of Review':part.css('span::text').extract_first(),
                'Nationality':part.css('span.small::text').extract_first(),
                'Contribution':part.css('span.social-member-MemberHeaderStats__bold--3z3qh::text').extract_first(),
                'Review Text':part.css('q.location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC>span::text').extract_first(),
                'Rating':part.css('div.location-review-review-list-parts-RatingLine__bubbles--GcJvM>span::attr(class)').extract(),
                }
            yield item
        NextPage='https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g295423-d320767-Reviews-or'+str(HotelabbasiSpider.page_number)
        if HotelabbasiSpider.page_number<860:
            HotelabbasiSpider.page_number=HotelabbasiSpider.page_number+5
            yield scrapy.Request(NextPage,callback=self.content_parse,dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: Why do not you try to add some logs, like printing the url that is being scraped or anything that can help you understand what your code is doing.

Comment: I tried running your code to figure out what the problem might be but it seems incomplete. How do I correctly run this snippet? Running content_parse() requires a response parameter; what and when is passed here?

Comment: If statement is out of for loop thats the reason it is only working for 5 and 10 page number